# Is Android keystore file enough for amazon Amazon Apps & Games Developer Portal

Tags: android, kindle

Hi I am new to Amazon Kindle.

I already uploaded an apk file to Google Play store.

Can I use same keystore file to export apk and publishing app in Amazon[Amazon Apps & Games Developer Portal](https://developer.amazon.com/myapps.html)

your help will be appreciated!.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same keystore for signing your apk.

But On submission to the Amazon Appstore, Amazon signs all of your apps with a secure key(that is different from your keystore) for your account.